# D3.js : Line Generation with dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I was working on a project today and ran into a problem, and since it's javascript I'm not entirely sure where the error is occurring. I am working with the D3 library for chart creation, and I have minimal experience with it.

The goal is to display blood-glucose data over a given period of time in a line chart. Right now I have it hard-coded so that it should display the last 2 days (x-axis), and have a range of readings between 0-300 (y-axis). The x and y axes are showing up, but when I try to draw a line (create a path) nothing is displayed.

The javascript is as follows:

```
var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    WIDTH= 1000,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    START = new Date(2015, 2, 16, 0, 0),        //static start date
    END = new Date(2015, 2, 18, 0, 0),      //static end date
    MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
    },

    xScale = d3.time.scale().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([START,END]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,300]),

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale),

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");

    vis.append("svg:g")         //append x-axis
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")        //repositions the x-axis lower
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.append("svg:g")         //append y-axis
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return xScale(d.datetime);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return yScale(d.BG);
        });

    var logs = [];          //empty array
      $.get( "show/log", function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                logs.push({"BG" : value["bg"], "datetime" : new Date(value["date"] + "T" + value["time"]) });
                console.log(logs);
            }); 
    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(logs))
        .attr('stroke', 'green')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none');

      });
```

Also, before anyone asks, "logs" is a valid array of objects before i pass it to "lineGen".

```
logs: [ 
    { BG: "276", datetime: Mon Feb 16 2015 13:52:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    { BG: "211", datetime: Mon Feb 16 2015 16:21:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    { BG: "109", datetime: Mon Feb 16 2015 17:55:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    { BG: "96", datetime: Mon Feb 16 2015 18:39:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    { BG: "150", datetime: Tue Feb 17 2015 06:49:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    { BG: "194", datetime: Tue Feb 17 2015 07:54:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) }
]
```

And, if I inspect the page after execution this path is in the page, but appears to be offscreen? or hidden?

```
<path d="M-12681.958333333334,56.79999999999998L-12633.84375,156.46666666666664L-12603.489583333334,312.8666666666667L-12589.28125,332.79999999999995L-12353.552083333334,250L-12332.5625,182.53333333333336" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></path>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste an example of your `logs` entries?

Comment: @BenLyall done, hope that helps. well, this is what logs looks like after data is parsed. each element of 'data' is an object that contains data, time, user id, blood glucose, insulin dose, and carbohydrates. but for this chart i am only interested in the date and time of the entry, and the glucose reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've created a snippet from your code and corrected some issues, give this a go:

```js
var vis,
    START = new Date(2015, 1, 16, 0, 0),        //static start date
    END = new Date(2015, 1, 18, 0, 0),      //static end date
    MARGINS = {
               top: 20,
               right: 20,
               bottom: 20,
               left: 50
              },
    WIDTH = 1000 - MARGINS.left - MARGINS.right,
    HEIGHT = 500 - MARGINS.top - MARGINS.bottom,

    logs = [ 
             { BG: "276", datetime: "Mon Feb 16 2015 13:52:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" },
             { BG: "211", datetime: "Mon Feb 16 2015 16:21:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" },
             { BG: "109", datetime: "Mon Feb 16 2015 17:55:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" },
             { BG: "96",  datetime: "Mon Feb 16 2015 18:39:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" },
             { BG: "150", datetime: "Tue Feb 17 2015 06:49:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" },
             { BG: "194", datetime: "Tue Feb 17 2015 07:54:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" }
           ],    

    xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, WIDTH]).domain([START,END]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT, 0]).domain([0,300]),

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(xScale)
                  .orient("bottom"),

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(yScale)
                  .orient("left");

    vis = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
              .attr("width", WIDTH + MARGINS.left + MARGINS.right)
              .attr("height", HEIGHT + MARGINS.top + MARGINS.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + MARGINS.left + "," + MARGINS.top + ")");

    vis.append("svg:g")         //append x-axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + HEIGHT + ")")        //repositions the x-axis lower
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.append("svg:g")         //append y-axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        //.attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) {
                            return xScale(d.datetime);
                        })
                        .y(function(d) {
                            return yScale(d.BG);
                        });

    /*
    var logs = [];          //empty array
      $.get( "show/log", function( data ) {
      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      console.log(value);
      logs.push({"BG" : value["bg"], "datetime" : new Date(value["date"] + "T" + value["time"]) });
      console.log(logs);
      }); 
     */ 

    logs.forEach(function(d) {
        d.datetime = new Date(d.datetime);
    });

    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(logs))
        .attr('stroke', 'green')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none');

//  });
```

```css
.axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualisation"></div>
```

Things that are different:

1. In javascript, the `month` of a `Date` object is actually zero referenced, ie. January = 0, February = 1, etc... your `START` and `END` variables were actually set to March, which is why your line had such big negative values.
2. You weren't appending an `svg` element to the DOM, you were just sticking your `g` elements directly in the `div#visualisation` element with no parent `svg`, so they weren't showing up.
3. I've made some other changes, using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 as an example.  In particular, I've created a parent `g` element to store all the graph elements in, allowing it to be translated by `MARGINS.top` and `MARGINS.left` as an entire entity, meaning you can completely forget about them inside that `g` element and just reference everything from `0, 0` making it easier to place all the svg elements.
4. Added styles for your axis and line, since the default `svg` styles are generally non-existent and look rubbish.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Now lets see how quickly I can break it by adding more functionality.